# Make my button say hello

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get started with VBA for Excel and have added the "Developer" tab to the ribbon. I have also in Module1 added a small sub:

```
Sub Hello()

    MsgBox ("Hello world!")

End Sub
```

Then I've created a button in spreadsheet 1, right click and assigned Hello as it's macro.

By now I'm thinking this should work, but when I click on it nothing happens.

Further more, if I open the VBA editor window again Module1 have been edited, not also containing my actions?

```
Sub Hello()

    MsgBox ("Hello world!")

End Sub
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 2")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "Hello"
    Range("G15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 2")).Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="Hello"
```

Whats this mambo jambo? And why does the button not work? :(

Comment: Did you correctly link the button to the right sub? The code after the sub seems generated by the macro recorder.

Comment: @user1383120: Sorry just saw your comments. I have deleted my answer. Jason94: That is because your macro recorder is "ON". Switch it off, remove unnecessary code from your module and try again :)

Comment: @user1383120: You might want to amend your post and post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes that was the stupidest thing I've ever said about a messagebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And try the messagebox without the parantheses, only the quotes. So: msgbox "Blabla" 
Delete the code after the sub routine: it was accidentally generated by the macro recorder (without a purpose).

Comment: Um yes, indeed. English is not my native language. So msgbox "blabla". I'll adapt

Comment: The parenthesis is not the cause of the error and hence I suggested that you mention about the macro recorder in your post :)

Comment: As an addition: You use the parantheses in case you want to do something like: sMsg = msgbox ("Do you want to save?", vbyesno)

Comment: Oh that's what you mean. I'll adapt.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
   Call hello  
 End Sub
```

1. Delete everything below `End Sub` ....this might have got recorded somewhere along the lines
2. Right click the button and go fo "View code" and adjust the automated code to look like the above. You'll need to be in "Design Mode" to get the menu when selecting the button:

[image]